# Как добавить данные в RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

Есть сервер с которого приложение получает JSON ответ вида:

```
{"success":1,"message":"Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT ","id_user":"1"}
{"success":1,"message":"Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT ","id_user":"1"}
{"success":1,"message":"Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT ","id_user":"1"}
```

И есть RecyclerView:

```
String[] myDataset = getDataSet();

mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
// создаем адаптер
mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(myDataset);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Вопрос, как в него добавить ответ с сервера.
Покуда у меня получилось лишь создать в нем список от 1 до 10:

```
private String[] getDataSet() {

    String[] mDataSet = new String[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        mDataSet[i] = "Статья" + i;
    }
    return mDataSet;
}
```

Нужно добавить в RecyclerView только `id` и `text`

Comment: Очевидно вам нужно написать свой адаптер, который будет биндить два типа данных (айди и текст) в айтемы. Для преобразования JSON в структуру, более пригодную для адаптера (например коллекция моделей) вам нужно его распарсить чем то, вроде библиотеки GSON.

Comment: @pavlofff а нельзя ли просто сохранить данные с `text` в String textStatya; а потом просто вставлять это в RecyclerView? только вот как? может есть какие либо примеры...

Comment: Если вам хочется придумать свой велосипед на тругольных колесах, то можно много чего чудного наделать. Нормальные люди парсят JSON в коллекцию моделей с помощью GSON и эту коллекцию отдают адаптеру на отображение в список. Это простой, эффективный и общепринятый способ, вы же можете сделать все по своему, если очень хочется - только, думаю, примеров такого чудного решения будет найти нелегко.

Comment: Дело в том, что для того, чтобы список мог отобразить данные, они должны быть преобразованы из ОДНОЙ сплошной строки в отдельные упорядоченные элементы для каждого `View` каждого айтема, чтобы адаптер мог получить простой и быстрый доступ к любой строке списка по ее номеру в этом списке. Лучше всего, если этим займется библиотека, разработанная специально для этого и написанная профессионалами, чем вы сами.

Comment: @pavlofff есть какие нибудь примеры реализации подобного?